# CloudWatch rule that is triggered after OpsWorks maintenance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-opsworks

I have an OpsWorks Puppet Enterprise instance that is located in a private subnet (no intention to change that). It can be accessed via a Route53 Records that is pointing to the instances private IP.

During the OpsWorks maintenance window the instance usually gets recreated, resulting in a weekly changing private IP. To compensate for that I have a Lambda that periodically updates the Record Set with the current IP.

This setup is working but I don't like its approach. I would prefer to trigger the Lambda by the finished maintenance and not periodically.

My idea was to use the AWS OpsWorks Stacks instance state change event as trigger, assuming that the recreation of the instance during maintenance results in its status changing to "online" at some point:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.opsworks"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "OpsWorks Instance State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "status": [
      "online"
    ]
  }
}
```

As it turned out, this event is never triggered during OpsWorks maintenance.

Therefore, does anyone have an idea which event can be used to trigger my Lambda right after the OpsWorks maintenance window?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: but with the online case your lamada would be triggered most of the time. you need to detect a change state something like online --> requested --> online...

Comment: As mentioned in my post, it isn't triggered at all. Seems like things are not the way I assumed them to be (there seems to be no instance status change to "online" at all).

Comment: ideally it should have triggered the lamda....can you check the CW metrics of the state it describes. Ideally if our assumption is right. Lamda should be triggered always when it is online